# Javascript not working in Chrome or Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, menu, show-hide

Hi everyone trying to get my menu working but it only does with Firefox.
None of the javascript is working, all the menu does is display everything open straight away, nothing is hidden.

Any help would be so much appreciated!!

The code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $(".toggle_container").hide();  
    $("h2.trigger").click(function()    
    {  
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");    
    });  
});  
</script>
```

Comment: you'll need to post some html. Or set it up on jsfiddle.net and post the link

Comment: Do you get an error in the console? click on the page, go to inspect element, check last tab (console)for errors. Also check if js is not disabled in preferences/content settings/javascript/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say how your HTML looks like and what exactly you want your script to do, but the script itself doesn't seem to have any obvious problems. It seems to work if your HTML is something like this:

```
<h2 class=trigger>trigger</h2>

<div class=toggle_container>
    <p>some div</p><p>with</p><p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Go to this address: http://jsfiddle.net/8DSgG/ and update the HTML with what you've got and see if it works. My bet would be that some of your classes in HTML are wrong, or they are IDs and not classes or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for replying and helping!! I updated that code with mine and it seems to work there even though I am using Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/8DSgG/1/ Why is it working there and not on my site? Perhaps the jquery template I am using? I have had some problems with it when I was trying to get it to work even in Firefox but that was regarding the CSS.